# configuring nodejs node : bad gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am putting my node server behind nginx. I have it working this way, but I believe it is not the best:

in bin/www

```
   server = https.createServer(config, app).listen(3210,'127.0.0.1');
   server.on('error', onError);
   server.on('listening', onListening);
```

in app.js

```
    app.use(session({
       name: app_config.get('session.name'),
       secret: env.get("SESSION_SECRET"), 
       cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true },
       store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
       touchAfter: app_config.get('session.touchAfter') 
                      })
    }));
```

nginx, demo.server.com

```
   server {
      listen 0.0.0.0:443;
      server_name demo.server.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/demo.server.com.log;
      location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3210;
            proxy_redirect off;
      }
     }
```

This works perfectly. My understanding is that the node server does not need to be in https mode. I modified as follow after much googling, and of course it does not work - I get "502 bad gateway". The server is up, and netstat -a shows that something is listening on the 3210 port.

in bin/www

```
   server = http.createServer(config, app).listen(3210,'127.0.0.1');
   server.on('error', onError);
   server.on('listening', onListening);
```

in app.js

```
    app.use(session({
       name: app_config.get('session.name'),
       secret: env.get("SESSION_SECRET"), 
       cookie: {secure: true },
       store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
       touchAfter: app_config.get('session.touchAfter') 
                      })
    }));
```

nginx, demo.server.com

```
   server {
      listen 0.0.0.0:443;
      server_name demo.server.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/demo.server.com.log;
      location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
           proxy_read_timeout 5m;
           proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3210;
            proxy_redirect off;
      }
     }
```

NGINX error log says:

```
2016/10/25 10:46:34 [error] 17278#0: *2 upstream prematurely closed    connection while reading response header  from upstream, client: xxxxx, server:  demo.server.com, request: "GET /itdemo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3210/itdemo", host: "demo.server.com"
```

What am I doing wrong ? thanks for any pointer and help

Comment: It works if I  do not put  " cookie: {secure: true }," but I wonder if the server is still secure ? it is because nginx is secured by ssl ?

Answer (score 0):

For plain HTTP servers, `createServer()` only accepts one argument, not two:

```
server = http.createServer(app).listen(3210,'127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: are you sure ? I read that I can put both arguments if I do not want the server to be called directly.

Comment: @Pat070 yeah pretty sure (although I should have said _"only accepts **at most** one argument_), [see the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener). Although I guess that it wasn't what was causing your problems :D

Comment: with https, this prevents the user doing https://demo.server.com:3210
how this is done with http? because without the second argument, I can call the node server directly on http://demo.server.com:3210/mydb
with the argument, that does not work - which is what I want

Comment: @Pat070 I think there's some confusion :) Communication between nginx and Node can be done over HTTP, as long as a) browsers communicate with nginx over HTTPS and b) nginx and Node are running on the same server. You probably have to look at the [`trust proxy`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) setting of Express, though.

Comment: Thanks. I am still confused. the docs you point to say that there is a function: server.listen([port][, hostname][, backlog][, callback])
why does this not apply to my case ?
i do use https for nginx, and both nginx and node are on the same machine.I am checking trust proxy now

Comment: @Pat070 I'm not talking about `listen()`, I'm talking about `createServer()`